# netlify lambda configuration in package.json

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, package.json, netlify

Im trying to follow this article https://www.netlify.com/blog/2018/07/09/building-serverless-crud-apps-with-netlify-functions-faunadb/

its a reactjs app.
we ran npm i netlify-lambda --save-dev
then did this configuration in package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-lambda",
  ...
  "proxy": {
    "/.netlify/functions": {
      "target": "http://localhost:9000",
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/\\.netlify/functions": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

someone plz explain what is happening here im newbie and dont understand syntax and  like ^/\.
and overall picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pathRewrite` is a regular expression.

- `^`: indicates the beginning of a string.

This will redirect the requests made to `/.netlify/functions` to the locally-running function server at port `9000` (due to `target` configuration).